# Comparing elements of a row in a 2d array. If elements after max element are not decreasing then smaller element should equal bigger element

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array, I want to compare the elements in a row. If the element is the MAX element, all the elements after it have to be in decreasing order. If not, make the smaller element that is out of place equal to the bigger one.
Example 1 1 5 2 4 is a row in my 2d array

11524 becomes 11544. here the max element is 5 and then all elements after it have to be in decreasing order which is not (2 then 4 is not decreasing order). So because of this turn 2 to 4.

This is the part of my code that unsuccessfully tackles this situation:

I am a beginner at coding and have been stuck on this for quite some time.
Help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I just fixed the indentation of the code as well as the confusing parts. Sorry I hand coded it on here instead of pasting it so I made mistakes in variable names etc. Also, thanks for pointing out that I was finding the max of the whole array, I fixed it into finding the max of every row!

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you can work on each row separately. You could solve the simpler problem of fixing numbers in a one dimensional array, then solve the original problem by looping over the rows.

Comment: Why is the code removed?